# Android ListView Item Border Width and Color

Tags: android, listview

How do I set the border between listview items. I need to have specific color and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the below link
[Custom ListView](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/)

By using Custom ListView we can set the width and color for the listview

Comment: How does one set border of selected list item? Thanks

Comment: for selected list item u got the position in ListView.onItemClicklistener().By using thta postion set the background color to that item

Answer (score 27):

Check this.

android:divider
            Drawable or color to draw between list items.

android:dividerHeight
           Height of the divider.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Comment: Ok.  thanks, how would one apply this specifically to the divider above/below selected item?

Comment: @Androider, a divider is not like CSS borders. A divider is simply one single element _between_ list items. That said, you can define the divider be a drawable with two lines.