# border of items of listview in android

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want to set border of Edittext and items of listview as in the picture  :

[image]

My xml code is as following :

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#BDD6E0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#BDD6E0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_pat_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_weight="4">

        </EditText> 

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#c0c0c0"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6" >

            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What can I do to draw border in the items of listview ?

Comment: What i would do is to create a nine patch of a simple black rectangle, and set it as background

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ListView Item Border Width and Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063609/android-listview-item-border-width-and-color)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

background of listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">    
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/edt_focused" />
</shape>
```

and add property to listview

```
android:divider="@drawable/list_divider" android:dividerHeight="1px"
```

Comment: What will be the value of  android:color="@color/edt_focused" ??

Comment: color which you want in border

Comment: What do you mean by "background of listview"? Are you saying `<ListView>` should have `android:background=@drawable/myshape` where `myshape.xml` is your first coded block? And what does `list_divider` refer to?

Answer (score 5):

Set the background of your list's child element as

```
 android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

and then in your res>drawable create a new **shape.xml**

like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="#FF000000" />


    </shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an xml drawable such as `/res/drawable/textlines.xml` and assign this as a Edittext's background property.

```
/res/drawable/textlines.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />

        </shape>
   </item>

   <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp"> 
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
   </item>

</layer-list>

You use this Drawable for EditText Background or List Item root Layout.
```

Answer (score 3):

To set the border in `ListView` set the property `android:divider="@drawable/img_list"` and `android:dividerHeight="1px"` to set the height of the divider.

Use the below code to set the border of `EditText`.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

So your EditText will look like. You can change the colors as per your needs.

[image]

Comment: I'm having issue with this. I also applied listSelector but the selector does not appear

Answer (score 1):

set following shape as the background of you list row item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >




    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set transcriptMode property of listview it will show the borders too.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" >
</ListView>
```

So don't need any shape xml.